# A single word for "a quick passing of sound"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

We have the word "flash" for "a quick passing of light". Do we have the equivalent for our auditory sense?

Comment: In some technical fields, the term *soundburst* is used to denote an isolated sound signal of short duration, analogous to a flash of light.

Comment: Quite there, but I suppose the word "burst" is quite general. As in, I can apply it to "lightburst". I'm looking for a more specific one, if any.

Comment: *burst* by itself is general, which's why they use *soundburst* as a new single word. It's required because the sense of both suddenness and loudness are needed. Else we already have *blip*, *crack*, *pip*, *bang*, *clap*, ... that do not have exact definitions.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm still interested, though, in knowing whether there is such word for sound that does not contain the word "burst". Thanks for the list of suggestions!

Comment: "Sonic boom" isn't what you are looking for... I'm throwing my brainstorming into the mix of comments here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fragmentary period of sound is called a ***burst*** of [noun describing sound]. E.g. *a burst of noise* or *a burst of birdsong*.

Comment: I guess I should go with "burst" for now. Will accept tomorrow if there is no better answer. Thanks Pitarou (and Kris for the comments)!

Answer (score 1):

### ***Swoosh***

*The sound produced by a sudden rush of air or liquid*

Comment: Nice one. I was expecting for something applicable in many situations, but from the comments I guess each word was created for a specific usage. So this answer is ok. =)

Answer (score 1):

How does 'peal' sound?  **(A loud burst of noise)**

*A peal of thunder*

Goes along with *a flash of lightning*.

Comment: ‘Peal’ to me means almost exactly the opposite: it implies that the sound is _prolonged_ or _repeated_. A peal of thunder is the same as a rolling of thunder, i.e., a lasting sound. Thunder is the sonic parallel to lightning, but unless you’re right up close to where the lightning strikes, it is not a brief burst of sound.  Moreover, ‘peal’ is associated with the (again, prolonged) ringing of bells, which is probably too specific for what the asker wants.

Comment: I've never heard about "peal" before. From what @JanusBahsJacquet explained, looks like it's a not-so-short event of noise, although it's not a continuous, very long noise. Good try, though.